# WPF - keyboard shortcuts to be captured by control even if not focused

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, lost-focus

I want when the user presses up/down to move within a listview even thought that listview is not in focus. But if the user is typing in a textbox and presses up down not to navigate anymore in the listview.
On possible solution is to add a PreviewKeyDown event for every element and if the captured key is up/down then pass it further down the tree but this solution does not seem very practical since I have a lot of elements.

Example code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="capturesUpDownWhenTextBoxNotFocused" ItemsSource="{Binding list}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}">
        <ListView.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Up" Command="{Binding upCommand}"></KeyBinding>
            <KeyBinding Key="Down" Command="{Binding downCommand}"></KeyBinding>
        </ListView.InputBindings>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Text="random text"></TextBox>
    <Button Content="button"></Button>
    <ListView x:Name="doesNotCaptureUpDownEvenIfFocused" ItemsSource="{Binding activeFile.activeFilters}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}"></ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the parent window only:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => 
        {
            var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModel;
            if(viewModel != null)
            {
                if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Up)
                {
                    viewModel.upCommand.Execute(null);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else if(e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Down)
                {
                    viewModel.downCommand.Execute(null);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }

        };
}
```

Then you don't need to handle it for any other element.

And no, there is no pure XAML solution for this.

Comment: yep that is the route I had taken after a googling around, thanks for the answer confirming this was a good approach